Combinatorial problem in $G(54,\, 5)$
I have asked (probably) easier versions of this question in the past, see MO379272 and MO380292. At the moment, it is not clear to me how the beautiful answers to those questions can be helpful here.
I am working on a problem in Combinatorial Group Theory related to the construction of some special fibred surfaces in Algebraic Geometry, and I would like to have a conceptual proof of the facts described below.
Let us consider the group $G=G(54, \, 5) =  (C_3 \times C_3) \rtimes C_6$, whose presentation is $$G=\langle a, \, b, \, x \; | \; a^3=b^3=x^6=1, \, [a, \, b]=1, \, xax^{-1} =a^{-1}b^{-1}, \, xbx^{-1}=b^{-1} \rangle$$
This group is monolithic, namely, the intersection $\operatorname{Mon}(G)$ of all non-trivial, normal subgroups is different from $1$; in fact, we have $\operatorname{Mon}(G) = \Phi(G)=\langle b \rangle \simeq C_3$.
I am looking for ordered $9$-tuples $$(\mathsf{r}_{11}, \, \mathsf{t}_{11}, \, \mathsf{r}_{12}, \, \mathsf{t}_{12}, \, \mathsf{r}_{21}, \,\mathsf{t}_{21}, \,  \mathsf{r}_{22}, \, \mathsf{t}_{22}, \, \mathsf{z})$$ of non-trivial elements in $G$, where $\mathsf{z} \in \operatorname{Mon}(G)$ and the following relations hold:
\begin{equation} 
\renewcommand{\t}{\mathsf{t}}
\renewcommand{\r}{\mathsf{r}}
\newcommand{\z}{\mathsf{z}}
\begin{aligned}
(R_1) & \, \, [\r_{11}, \, \r_{22}]=1 & (R_6) & \, \,
[\r_{12}, \, \r_{22}]=1 \\
(R_2) & \, \, [\r_{11}, \, \r_{21}]=1 &
(R_7) & \, \, [\r_{12}, \, \r_{21}]=
\z^{-1}\,\r_{21}\,\r_{22}^{-1}\,\z\,\r_{22}\,\r_{21}^{-1} \\
(R_3) & \, \, [\r_{11}, \, \t_{22}]=1 & (R_8) & \, \,
[\r_{12}, \, \t_{22}]=\z^{-1} \\
(R_4) & \, \, [\r_{11}, \, \t_{21}]=\z^{-1} & (R_9) & \, \,
[\r_{12}, \, \t_{21}]=[\z^{-1}, \, \t_{21}] \\
(R_5) & \, \, [\r_{11}, \, \z]=[\r_{21}^{-1}, \, \z] & (R_{10})
& \, \, [\r_{12}, \, \z]=[\r_{22}^{-1}, \, \z] \\
 & & & \\
(T_1) & \, \, [\t_{11}, \, \r_{22}]=1 & (T_6) & \, \,
[\t_{12}, \, \r_{22}]= \t_{22}^{-1}\, \z \,\t_{22} \\
(T_2) & \, \, [\t_{11}, \, \r_{21}]= \t_{21}^{-1}\, \z \, \t_{21} & (T_7) & \, \, [\t_{12}, \, \r_{21}]=[\t_{22}^{-1}, \, \z] \\
(T_3) & \, \, [\t_{11}, \, \t_{22}]=1 & (T_8) & \, \,
[\t_{12}, \, \t_{22}]=[\t_{22}^{-1}, \, \z] \\
(T_4) & \, \, [\t_{11}, \, \t_{21}]=[\t_{21}^{-1}, \, \z] & (T_9) & \, \,
[\t_{12}, \, \t_{21}]=[\t_{22}^{-1}, \, \z]\,\t_{21}\, [\z, \, \t_{22}^{-1}]\,\t_{21}^{-1}\\
(T_5) & \, \, [\t_{11}, \, \z]=[\t_{21}^{-1}, \, \z] & (T_{10})
& \, \, [\t_{12}, \, \z]=[\t_{22}^{-1}, \, \z] \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Doing computations with GAP4, I verified the following

Proposition 1. No such a $9$-tuple exists.

In fact a stronger result holds:

Proposition 2. No such a $9$-tuple exists, even without the assumption $\z \in \operatorname{Mon}(G)$.

I tried to give a proof of this result by hand, but I soon got stuck in some endless case-by-case analysis. I guess that there is some clever method to do the computation, so let me ask the

Question. Is there a way to prove the proposition(s) above without using the computer?

Added: As explained in the comments, the above set of relations is strictly related to some braid relations in genus $2$.

Can you give any motivation for the relations ($R_i)$ and $(T_i)$? They look random to my ignorant eyes, so it's hard to conceive how one would sensibly start trying to verify them.

@NickGill They are related to some braid group representation in genus $2$. The nine elements correspond to the nine generators of a braid group with two strands on a "torus with two holes". The first eight come from the realization of the surface as the identification space of an octagon, whereas $\mathsf{z}$ is the square of the standard braid exchanging the two base points.

The relations come from the braid relations in genus 2

Thanks! That's helpful.

By $[a,b]$ do you mean $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$ or $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$?

@JohnShareshian $[a, , b] = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$
